# CURL's weird behavior (error 400) when making http request

Tags: c, http, curl, request, libcurl

I have such code that makes http request to Yandex Translate API:

```
const char url[] = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate";
const char key[] = "secret.key.here";
char buf[4096] = { 0 };
char input[1024] = "Hello world. H";
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s?key=%s&lang=ru&text=\"%s\"", 
         url, key, input);

struct string response;
init_string(&response);

CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, buf);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", 
                curl_easy_strerror(res));
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}

printf("%s\n", response.data);
```

After `snprintf` execution, `buf` contains such url:

```
https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=secret.key.here&lang=ru&text="Hello world. H"
```

and after response, `response.data` contains:

```
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

but if I reassign `char input[1024] = "Hello world.";` (without "H"), after http request, I get the proper response:
`{"code":200,"lang":"en-ru","text":["\"Здравствуй, мир!\"."]}`.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried sending other text that is not English. The web site may be using HTTP response code 400 to tell you that you have to send it actual English or it can't translate it. So it has nothing to do with curl itself.

Comment: @TJohnson `echo -n "Hello world. T" | ./translate
{"code":200,"lang":"en-ru","text":["\"Здравствуй, мир. Т\""]}`. Screenshot from terminal http://s32.postimg.org/lsber5asl/Screen_Shot_2016_05_01_at_20_30_51.png. However, when I make the same request through browser, I get code 200.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode your input text for usage in URL. Try this curl [function](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_escape.html)

```
char *input = curl_easy_escape(curl, "Hello world. H", 0);
```